# Convert UTC to MDT via MySQL

Tags: mysql, linux

I'm having trouble changing my queries to use the my current MDT timezone. The server and MySQL are UTC

```
`date` = Tue Aug  9 23:32:52 UTC 2016
SELECT NOW() = 2016-08-09 23:33:28
cat /etc/localtime = UTC0
```

When I try to run CONVERT_TZ() to US/Mountain, my time is way off.

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ( CURDATE( ) , 'UTC', 'US/Mountain' )
```

Returns 2016-08-08 18:00:00

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: BTW.. my current MDT time is Tue Aug  9 17:32:09 MDT 2016

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `curdate`, you should use `now` like you did in your example:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ( NOW() , 'UTC', 'US/Mountain' )
```

`curdate` only returns the date, not the time.  So converting `2016-08-09` to `US/Mountain` would offset it by 6 hours and return the previous day.

Comment: If `UTC` and `US/Mountain` aren't defined, you may need to do something like this:
`SELECT CONVERT_TZ( NOW(), '+00:00', '-07:00') as MST;` or
`SELECT CONVERT_TZ( NOW(), '+00:00', '-06:00') as MDT;` which admittedly is less useful, but is good to know if that query doesn't work because they're not defined, as was the case with me.